# Macbook Pro becomes very hot after a minute or two of high CPU use

Tags: temperature, cooling

My Macbook Pro seems to become very hot after just a minute or two of high CPU usage by iCloud related processes. Is there any way to improve cooling. This happens while using my Macbook on a woden desk, I've tried the standard SMC Resets and other suggestions but to no avail :(

Comment: How old is it? When was it last stripped & cleaned? What temperatures are reported?

Comment: @Tetsujin It's a Macbook Pro 2015 Retina I got in June. Opening up the Mac would void warranty so stripped and cleaned has never happened. Temperatures range from 65 degrees celsius to 105 degrees celsius in extreme circumstances. I'd like to be able to use 100% of my resources without risking my system catching on fire.